# Preventing Qt window from closing in hooked application, Eventfilter does nothing

Tags: c++, qt, hook

I have hooked an application, which uses Qt. The application often shows popup windows, when the popups are closed, the parent window of the popup dialog also gets closed.

I have written an EventFilter which is supposed to prevent the parent windows from closing. I can see in the debugger, that the EventFilter is called, but the windows close anyway.

This is the filter:

```
bool CloseEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject* object, QEvent* event){
printf("%s\n", parseEvent(event).c_str());
if(event->type() == QEvent::Close){
    event->accept();
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::Hide){
    event->accept();
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::HideToParent){
    event->accept();
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::Destroy){
    event->accept();
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::DeferredDelete){
    event->accept();
    return true;
}
if(event->type() == QEvent::ChildRemoved){
    event->accept();
    return true;
}
return false;
```

}

Is there anytrhing wrong with the filter? Are the other ways to do it?

Comment: What logic is used by the Application to close the parent window when the child window closes? How do you know it is using the event system after all? For example, it might have an individual signal/slot connection established.

Comment: I am not sure what logic is used exactly, I hoped to be able to solve it without looking into the disassembly. I tried disconnect() and blockSignals() on the parent widget, but it still closes.

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-mainwindows-application-example.html#close-event-handler The Close event should not be accepted, but explicitely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

The `CloseEvent` is not an event that is processed by closing the window. Closing the window happens after the event is fired at the point where it was fired. Therefore accepting the event in a filter might stop it from propagating, but not stop the window closing.

When catching a `CloseEvent`, you are having a chance to **ignore** the event instead of accepting it. The window closing will only happen if the event was accepted, which is the default.

> The isAccepted() function returns true if the event's receiver has agreed to close the widget; call accept() to agree to close the widget and call ignore() if the receiver of this event does not want the widget to be closed.

This means that in your code you need to call `event->ignore()` instead of `event->accept()`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it still closes when I call ignore() instead of accept()